# Como definir o nome do meu pacote no PyPi?

Tags: python, pip

Estou criando um modulo python para distribuir no pypi, estou estudando o processo de criação de distribuição dos módulos por alguns tutoriais e pelo próprio guia do pypi, mas mesmo assim ainda estou com algumas duvidas. Segue a arvore do meu projeto para ajudar com as perguntas:

```
    |_ meupacote
      |_ DESCRIPTION.rst
      |_ LICENSE
      |_ README.md
      |_ setup.cfg
      |_ setup.py
      |_ src
        |_ __pycache__
        |_ __init__.py
        |_ __main__.py
        |_ meupacote.py
      |_ tests
      |_ venv
```

Eu queria saber:

1 - Qual vai ser o nome que vai ficar no modulo, se vai ser "meupacote" ou vai ficar "src"?

2 - Como que vai ficar na hora de importar, depois que o modulo estiver pronto e distribuído?

3 - Tem alguma coisa que eu possa fazer em "setup" ou em outo lugar pra especificar como eu quero que fique o modulo/pacote?

Ps.: O nome "meupacote" é meramente ilustrativo.

Comment: considere a possibilidade de edtar o titulo da pergunta para refletir melhor o conteúdo. Algo como "Como definir o nome do meu pacote no PyPi?"

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas as meta-informações do seu pacote (como nome, versão, autor, etc) ficam no arquivo `setup.py`. Aqui um exemplo de arquivo desse tipo:

```py
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
  name = 'YOURPACKAGENAME',          
  packages = ['YOURPACKAGENAME'],   
  version = '0.1',       
  license='MIT',        
  description = 'TYPE YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE',   
  author = 'YOUR NAME',                  
  author_email = 'your.email@domain.com',      
  url = 'https://github.com/user/reponame',   
  download_url = 'https://github.com/user/reponame/archive/v_01.tar.gz',    
  keywords = ['SOME', 'MEANINGFULL', 'KEYWORDS'],   
  install_requires=[            
          'validators',
          'beautifulsoup4',
      ],
  classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',      
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',      
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',   
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',      
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
  ],
)
```

Note que `PACKAGENAME` é o nome que seu pacote vai receber no PyPi e que você vai usar para importar.

Esse setup.py de exemplo eu tirei desse [texto](https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56). Sempre uso ele quando crio um novo pacote.

Se quiser ver um exemplo prático, veja os arquivos desse [pacote](https://github.com/lucascr91/congressbr) que criei recentemente.