# Como criar um programa executavel com python e publica na PyPI

Tags: python

Quero criar um comando no terminal linux eu criei um programa simples ( atualizar a distro linux ) com Python e publiquei na PyPI mas quanto e baixei e digitei o nome dele não foi executado pior disse que não existia um comando com esse nome fiz várias tentativas e não consegui.

Queria que executasse como estivesse no meu ambiente mas não está funcionando.

main do programa:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
from subprocess import check_output, call
 
def process():
       print('UPDATE')
       update = check_output('sudo apt update', shell=True)
       call('clear', shell=True)
 
       print('UPGRADE')
       upgrade = check_output('sudo apt upgrade', shell=True)
       call('clear', shell=True)
 
       if (update or upgrade == True):
           call('clear', shell=True)
           print('Your system is up to date')
       else:
           call('clear', shell=True)
           print('Erro')
process()
```

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
import os
import re
 
with open('README.md', 'rb') as f:
   readme = f.read().decode('utf-8')
 
with open(os.path.join('__init__.py'), 'rb') as f:
   init_py = f.read().decode('utf-8')
 
version = re.search(
   '^__version__ = [\'\"]([^\'\"]+)[\'\"]', init_py, re.MULTILINE
).group(1)
author = re.search(
   '^__author__ = [\'\"]([^\'\"]+)[\'\"]', init_py, re.MULTILINE
).group(1)
email = re.search(
   '^__email__ = [\'\"]([^\'\"]+)[\'\"]', init_py, re.MULTILINE
).group(1)
 
setup(
   name='upug',
   packages=find_packages(),
   version=version,
   description='Update linux systems',
   long_description=readme,
   long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
   author=author,
   author_email=email,
   url='https://github.com/ward910/UpUg',
   install_requires=[],
   license='MIT',
   keywords=['GNU/linux', 'linux', 'python3'],
   classifiers=[
       'Intended Audience :: Developers',
       'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
       'Natural Language :: English',
       'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
   ],
)
```

[Repositório](https://github.com/ward910/UpUg)
[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/upug/)

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/498357/como-definir-o-nome-do-meu-pacote-no-pypi/498366#498366

Answer (score 1):

Está faltando o argumento `entry_points` no seu `setup.py`. Esse argumento define os "pontos de entrada" do seu pacote, isto é, indica qual *função do seu pacote* você deseja associar com um *nome de comando* no console.

Exemplo:

```
setup(
    # outros argumentos vão aqui ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'nome-do-comando=modulo.arquivo:funcao',
            'outro-comando=modulo.submodulo:outra_funcao'
        ]
)
```

Depois de instalado, o pacote permite acessar diretamente a função `modulo.arquivo:funcao` com o comando de terminal `nome-do-comando`.

Note que, neste caso, estou assumindo que há um arquivo chamado `arquivo.py` dentro da pasta `modulo` (a partir da raiz do seu pacote), e neste arquivo há uma função chamada `funcao`.